# Debugging Visual C++ complex project

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

I am working on a bit complex project, and i wonder is it possible to debug just part of code not entire application because its too slow.
Like i write some lines and code, compile, and then tell to debugger from where to start execution and to assign variable values manually.

Comment: Maybe, it rarely comes to a good end.  This is why programmers write unit tests and like Edit+Continue.

Comment: Sounds a lot like unit testing; write an small driver code that startups and configures the environment and then calls your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible if you set up the environment for your part of code which will model the real project. Look at [mock objects](http://www.mockobjects.com/) ([brief description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)).